# Moving HTML Objects On Arrow Key Press

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, keydown

I want to navigate through a div contents (div with attribute `id="brand_div"`), while pressing key up and down keys press.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="brand_search_box"  id="brand_searchterm" placeholder="Select Your Brand">


<div id="brand_div" class="c_result" style="display: block;">
<a class="brand_sugg" href="#">
<div class="c_result show">Medicine</div>
</a>

<a class="brand_sugg" href="#">
<div class="c_result show">sandals</div>
</a>

<a class="brand_sugg" href="#">
<div class="c_result show">Dress</div>
</a>
</div>

// OnkeyUp Code

 $('#brand_searchterm').on('keyup', function (e) {

        var key = $('#brand_searchterm').val();
        if (key)
        {
            if (req)
                req.abort();
                req = $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>home/brand_search_sugg",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    brand_search: key
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data)
                    {   
                        $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
                        $("#brand_div").html(data).show();
                        if($('#brand_div a:focus').length==0){$('#brand_div a').first().focus();}
                        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
                        {   
                            $("#brand_div a:focus").next().focus();
                        } 
                        if(e.keyCode==38)
                        {           
                           $("#brand_div a:focus").prev().focus();
                        }                           
                    }
                }

            });
        } 
    });
```

this code is working perfectly.. but when I click key down arrow each time the window's scroll bar is moving down, and when I press keyup the scroll bar is scrolling up.....

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // space and arrow keys
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

This code will avoid the scrolling of page when user press up or down arrow.

or you can make AJAX call on on scroll height.

If data returned by service is empty you can navigate to next div.

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){

    // grab the scroll amount and the window height
    var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
    var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

    if(scrollPercent > 50) {
        // run a function called doSomething
       doSomething();
    }

    function doSomething() { 

        // do something when a user gets 50% of the way down my page

    }

});
```

Comment: I need to scroll the contents through <div id="brand_div"></div>, This Code will prevent all scrolling..

Comment: you can make the ajax call based scroll height.